# AndroidManifest tags in Android directory are unknown to Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

I need to have some native Android codes and configs in my Flutter project, for example in AndroidManifest.xml file. But attributes of the tags that I add are unknown (red colored) and not working, specifically `<receiver>` and `<intent-filter>` tags that I use here.

I also need to address some native java files located in a Flutter library and I don't know how to that too!

Following are my manifest image in my IDE and its code:

[image: android manifest snapshot]

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.flutterapp">

    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="my app"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>





        <receiver android:name = ".SmsReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">

            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="sms"
                    android:host="*"
                    android:port="1235" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: You have to open your flutter project's android native part from open project option by selecting android option under your flutter project. On that you will see android native part. open manifest file here you will not get any red colored here. Also if you want to do any native code. you should work here.

Comment: I can't see that option you said

Comment: If you are using android studio editor. Select File from menu then select open option. then you can continue as i sad.

Comment: You probably have an error somewhere in your code which does not allow gradle to complete it's process. That's why those red texts appear. Also make sure your xml is valid (I don't see <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> at the beginning of your manifest)

Comment: No Amin I don't have any error and gradle build is done completely, adding `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` in my manifest file didn't solve my problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter editor in Android Studio doesn't have proper lint check for Android project code. To access the Android project with proper lint check, it's better to open it via **Tools > Flutter > Open Android module in Android Studio**

[image: Opening Android Module]